# get existing SQL plan for Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I would like to view my old existing SQL plan at my PostgreSQL

I am aware Oracle have a view called `DBA_HIST_SQL_PLAN`
tried to google 'existing or old SQL plan PostgreSQL but could not find something related.

I don't want to use `PREPARE STATMENT` - since it will limit me.

How can I get the existing plan on my PostgreSQL DB

Comment: You can't. Postgres doesn't store the plans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [`debug_print_plan` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) allows to store execution plans to the server logs (just checked it).

Comment: There is debug_print_plan : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html , but it prints to the syslog.

Comment: @joop [logging_collector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOGGING-COLLECTOR)

Comment: Or use the [auto explain module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by “old” here:

> I would like to view my old existing SQL plan at my PostgreSQL

I will assume you need to find a recorded `EXPLAIN` output (the execution plan) after noticing a query that you want to examine.

If you are willing to slow down your queries and generate a lot more logging output, you can [configure PostgreSQL to write the execution plan to the log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) automatically for queries that meet some specified criteria:

> The `auto_explain` module provides a means for logging execution plans of slow statements automatically, without having to run `EXPLAIN` by hand. This is especially helpful for tracking down un-optimized queries in large applications. […] Of course there is a price in overhead for that.
>
> […]
>   There are several configuration parameters that control the behavior of `auto_explain`. Note that the default behavior is to do nothing, so you must set at least `auto_explain.log_min_duration` if you want any results.
>
> […]
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> postgres=# LOAD 'auto_explain';
> postgres=# SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
> postgres=# SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;
> postgres=# SELECT count(*)
>            FROM pg_class, pg_index
>            WHERE oid = indrelid AND indisunique;
> ```
>
> This might produce log output such as:
>
> ```
> LOG:  duration: 3.651 ms  plan:
>   Query Text: SELECT count(*)
>               FROM pg_class, pg_index
>               WHERE oid = indrelid AND indisunique;
>   Aggregate  (cost=16.79..16.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3.626..3.627 rows=1 loops=1)
>     ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.17..16.55 rows=92 width=0) (actual time=3.349..3.594 rows=92 loops=1)
>           Hash Cond: (pg_class.oid = pg_index.indrelid)
>           ->  Seq Scan on pg_class  (cost=0.00..9.55 rows=255 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.140 rows=255 loops=1)
>           ->  Hash  (cost=3.02..3.02 rows=92 width=4) (actual time=3.238..3.238 rows=92 loops=1)
>                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4kB
>                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_index  (cost=0.00..3.02 rows=92 width=4) (actual time=0.008..3.187 rows=92 loops=1)
>                       Filter: indisunique
> ```